# Perl: Hash within Array within Hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, perl-data-structures

I am trying to build a Hash that has an array as one value; this array will then contain hashes. Unfortunately, I have coded it wrong and it is being interpreted as a psuedo-hash. Please help!

```
my $xcHash       = {};
my $xcLine;

#populate hash header

$xcHash->{XC_HASH_LINES} = ();

#for each line of data
    $xcLine       = {};

    #populate line hash

    push(@{$xcHash->{XC_HASH_LINES}}, $xcLine);

foreach $xcLine ($xcHash->{XC_HASH_LINES})
    #psuedo-hash error occurs when I try to use $xcLine->{...}
```

Comment: Including `use strict; use warnings;` would have revealed the problem for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$xcHash->{XC_HASH_LINES}` is an arrayref and not an array. So

```
$xcHash->{XC_HASH_LINES} = ();
```

should be:

```
$xcHash->{XC_HASH_LINES} = [];
```

`foreach` takes a list. It can be a list containing a single scalar (`foreach ($foo)`), but that's not what you want here.

```
foreach $xcLine ($xcHash->{XC_HASH_LINES})
```

should be:

```
foreach my $xcLine (@{$xcHash->{XC_HASH_LINES}})
```

Comment: "forward-declaring" `$xcHash->{XC_HASH_LINES}` is not necessary at all though, as it will be autovivified on first use.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach $xcLine ($xcHash->{XC_HASH_LINES})
```

should be

```
foreach $xcLine ( @{ $xcHash->{XC_HASH_LINES} } )
```

See http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference for easy to remember rules for how to dereference complex data structures.

Answer (score 2):

#### Golden Rule #1

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

It might seem like a fight at the beginning, but they will instill good Perl practices and help identify many syntactical errors that might otherwise go unnoticed.

---

Also, Perl has a neat feature called autovivification. It means that `$xcHash` and `$xcLine` need not be pre-defined or constructed as references to arrays or hashes.

The issue faced here is to do with the not uncommon notion that a scalar can hold an array or hash; it doesn't. What it holds is a reference. This means that the `$xcHash->{XC_HASH_LINES}` is an arrayref, not an array, which is why it needs to be dereferenced as an array using the `@{...}` notation.

Comment: Thanks! I do include strict & warnings in my code; I just omitted it here for brevity.

Comment: @David : Then you must've posted the code from memory. The code you've posted would not run under the strict and warnings pragmas.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

```
my %xcHash;
```

for each line of data:

```
push @{$xcHash{XC_HASH_LINES}},$xcLine;
```

Comment: While this is valid advice, it doesn't address the issue at hand